# JGroups hangs at GMS: address is

Tags: java, cluster

On starting the Alfresco service it hangs at this line when, AIUI JGroups is attempting to join the cluster. Left for half an hour it didn't timeout and move on.

Any suggestions as to what might cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, it seems it was down to a node on the cluster already being online but preventing other nodes starting up - the node already on the network was suffering from a full disk partition.